# How to click all update buttons in a GridView programmatically using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some TextBox in ItemTemplate. It allow users to edit multiple rows.

'Button1' can update one row. I want to click all of it in one page using a button outside GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("something") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices%>'
    UpdateCommand="...">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am looking for some thing like this:

```
For i = 0 To Me.GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    SqlDataSource1.Update(i) //pseudo
Next
```

I want to reuse `UpdateCommand` in `SqlDataSource1`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an update function or subroutine then call it as you needed. Something like this

```
        Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal cmd As String, ByVal cmdType As CommandType, Optional ByVal parameters() As SqlParameter = Nothing) As Integer
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing
        Dim command As SqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim res As Integer = -1
        Try
            connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            command = New SqlCommand(cmd, connection)
            command.CommandType = cmdType
            Me.AssignParameters(command, parameters)
            connection.Open()
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            command.Transaction = transaction
            res = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            transaction.Commit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not (transaction Is Nothing) Then
                transaction.Rollback()
            End If
            Throw New SqlDbException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
        Finally
            If Not (connection Is Nothing) AndAlso (connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then connection.Close()
            If Not (command Is Nothing) Then command.Dispose()
            If Not (transaction Is Nothing) Then transaction.Dispose()
        End Try
        Return res
    End Function
```

That is a reusable function for executing non-query command.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use `SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand` property.

Answer (score 0):

I just known how to do it. I answer my own question. It works.

**.aspx**

```
UpdateCommand="..." //SQL Update Command
<UpdateParameters>
    //Some Parameters
</UpdateParameters>
```

**.aspx.vb**

```
For i = 0 To Me.GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Me.GridView1.UpdateRow(i, True)
Next
```